# Get JS Variable in Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax response which returns html and javascript as follows:

```
<div class="contents">
  <div>1</div>
  <script>
    var test = "test";
  </script>
</div>
```

How can I access the variable test?

Comment: Only if you insert it into the dom

Comment: You inject the response into the page, then access the `test` variable.

Comment: you can access it normally i think

Comment: No way around inserting it?  Seems like wasted performance if my variable is large.

Comment: Due to some template limitations it isn't possible to return the response as json.

Answer (score 0):

Append the response in some temp div, get the value from variable and remove the div.

```
$("<div id='dvTemp'></div>").html(AjaxResponse).appendTo("body");
alert(test);
$("#dvTemp").remove();
```